# How to use hd5f to access to nested structures in *.mat files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, dictionary

I try to get access to the following structure of matlab file (*.mat):

[parent matlab structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfXuC.png)

which contains the following set of structures

[nested structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8CE6.png)

I try to access to the fields inside each structure using **hd5f** python lib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jbyc.png)

using the following code:

```
mat_dict = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')
result = mat_dict['JKPRR']['results']['ChangingKnob'][0]['result']
```

But apparently I can't go deep from:

```
result = mat_dict['JKPRR']['results']['ChangingKnob'][0]
```

Could anybody knows how I can go to the deeper fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution & discussion in following issue:

https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1668

First, the easy bit: it looks like the ChangingKnob dataset is 2D, so to get one item out, you need two indices:

```
mat_dict['JKPRR']['results']['ChangingKnob'][0, 0]
```

This is equivalent but a bit easier to read:

```
mat_dict['JKPRR/results/ChangingKnob'][0, 0]
```

It looks like Matlab is storing HDF5 references (a kind of link) in the dataset, so then you need to follow the reference:

```
> ref = mat_dict['JKPRR/results/ChangingKnob'][0, 0] dataset =
> mat_dict[ref]
```

Hopefully after that you can do dataset['result'] to access one field, unless Matlab has made more obstacles.